# Unable to deserialize Object[] to class using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize this `Json` element in my code Json array to a custom class .. but i couldn't :

```
ObjectMapper OMapper = new ObjectMapper();
OMapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true);
OMapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
OMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
OMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
OMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

JsonNode node = OMapper.readTree("{\"headers\":[\"st1\", \"ddf2\", \"sdsd\"]}");


headers h = OMapper.treeToValue(node.get("headers"), headers.class);
```

and this is the class :

```
public class headers{   
    public headers(){
        System.out.println("dssdsd");

    }

    @JsonSetter
    public void set(){
        System.out.println("ASAASAAS");
    }

    @JsonGetter()
    public JsonNode get(int index){
        System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXx");
        return null;
    }
}
```

but i'm getting this error :

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of headers out of START_ARRAY token  at [Source:
>   UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:62)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1307)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1116)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1070)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1447)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:173)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify `headers` as an array.

```
headers[] h = OMapper.treeToValue(node.get("headers"), headers[].class);
```

Comment: Thanks , but how can read the JsonNode from headers[] ? getter and setters ?